# UI tests fail in Xcode bot with error "UI Testing Failure - App state is still not terminated"

Tags: xcode-bots, xcode-ui-testing

I am running UI tests in a single Xcode bot. The bots are run on a separate computer which is only used for this task and nothing else. The tests start running fine at first, but after several successful runs they start all failing with this error.

> UI Testing Failure - App state is still not terminated

After the first test fails with this error - all tests after it fail as well. The only cure I found is to restart the server computer. How can I prevent this error?

OS X 10.11 (15A263e), Xcode 7.0 (7A192o), OS X Server 5.0.1 (15S2235)

Comment: Have you find the solution for this?I need a solution but i couldnt get it from anywhere

Comment: No I have not found a solution, but I have sent a bug report to Apple, let us hope it will be fixed soon.

Comment: @Evgenii Any update from Apple on this?

Comment: @LironYahdav nothing yet, still waiting for Apple's response

Comment: I am having the same issue specially after updating to Xcode 7.2(7C68). There no updates from Apple's side https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13234 . Currently, The issue is less to happen when I am testing on Simulator iPhone 6 (iOS 9.2). But It is more frequent to happen when I perform UI Testing on Real Device

Comment: Try the way mentioned here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33359023/ui-test-fails-when-it-types-text-into-a-text-view-when-run-by-an-xcode-bot?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33359023/ui-test-fails-when-it-types-text-into-a-text-view-when-run-by-an-xcode-bot?rq=1)