# UI test fails when it types text into a text view when run by an Xcode bot

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, xcode-ui-testing

I have the following XCTest UI test that types text into a text view.

```
let textView = app.textViews.elementBoundByIndex(0)
textView.tap()
textView.typeText("Hello world")
```

When run as an Xcode bot it shows the following error for the `typeText` call.

> Assertion: UI Testing Failure - failed: Timed out waiting for key event to complete

[image]

Interestingly, when I run it manually from the Xcode on the same computer the test passes. This test also passed in Xcode bot before upgrade to Xcode 7.1 / iOS 9.1. What can be the source of the problem?

Here is an isolated demo with the UI test:
https://github.com/exchangegroup/UITestTextViewDemo

iOS 9.1 Simulator, OS X 10.11.1 (15B42), Xcode 7.1 (7B91b), OS X Server 5.0.15 (15S4033)

Reported to Apple.

Comment: Apple screwed something up with XC7.1/iOS 9.1 update for Bots. Our green test suite turned to red in an instant. Failing with either this error, "Timeout waiting for screenshot" or "Timeout starting the sim". I really hope that XC7.2 will fix this.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue.  I don't think I have a "fix", but I've found that if I 'wait' a little longer, sometimes the test will pass.  My particular issue is with a WKWebView that has an internal "content editable" field, but the principle here is the same.  After a 'tap' on the editor, I issue a run-loop wait: NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().runUntilDate(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3))

Comment: something new? i have the same problem in xcode 7.3.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution for my case and I hope it helps you as well.

In my `setUp()` and `tearDown()` (seems redundant I know) I put `XCUIApplication().terminate()`. This is ensuring that the app is terminated before running the next test and it seems to be doing the job.

```
override func setUp() {
    XCUIApplication().terminate()
    super.setUp()
    continueAfterFailure = false
    XCUIApplication().launch()
}
override func tearDown() {
    super.tearDown()
    XCUIApplication().terminate()
}
```

I filed a bug with Apple but for the time being this is getting me around the error that you were seeing. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 20):

I believe the underlying issue is that "Connect Hardware Keyboard" is turned on by default. Even if you turn it off for the main user, the _xcsbuildd user still uses the default. I was able to solve the problem by adding a pre test action to the scheme with the following script:

```
if [ `defaults read com.apple.iphonesimulator ConnectHardwareKeyboard` -eq 1 ]
 then
  defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator ConnectHardwareKeyboard -bool false
  killall "Simulator"
fi
```

[image]

Comment: The script is really useful, I always have to remember to disable hardware keyboard while running tests on my dev machine. I never experienced this problem on the Xcode Server, but it is useful to have just to make sure it works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I found out another solution, since the one proposed by Konnor wasn't working for me: I was having a lot of problems using UITest on Xcode Bot, and the common symptom was that testing on simulator took a lot more time than on the local machine, so I thought that the _xcsbuildd user used to run the tests was in some way slowed down.

My solution is simple: just promote _xcsbuildd user to be a "normal" user. This has another advantage: if you want you can login with that user and see the tests run in the simulator during integration, so it is easier to debug!

Here is how I did it:

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/_xcsbuildd UserShell /bin/bash
sudo dscl . -create /Users/_xcsbuildd FirstName Xcode
sudo dscl . -create /Users/_xcsbuildd LastName Server
sudo dscl . -create /Users/_xcsbuildd FullName "Xcode Server"
sudo dscl . -create /Users/_xcsbuildd PrimaryGroupID 20
```

Then change the password with:

```
sudo dscl . -passwd /Users/_xcsbuildd
```

I was not able to make the user show up in the fast login window, anyway you should see a "other user" where you can insert the username "_xcsbuildd" and the password you chose

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well. I have written a UI test to capture screenshots with Snapshot (fastlane) and it runs fine on an iPad Air & Pro simulator. However, on an iPad Retina or iPad 2 simulator I get this error message, either running from command line or directly from Xcode.

A solution in my case was to add some sleep() functions between the typeText() statements and the error went away.

**Edit**: this only fixes running manually from Xcode, through command line it still causes a test failure. I also noticed that it works on all simulators for 64-bit devices, but not on earlier devices.

**Edit 2**: I found a way to work around this issue by using the iOS 9.0 simulator instead of iOS 9.3, as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36334816/5334132. This seems a good workaround until it gets fixed in a new version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Other than connect hardware keyboard, none of these things really worked for me. What did work was **turning off the Mac's screen saver and display sleep** in system settings. My suspicion is the simulator performs oddly when the Mac is locked or doesn't have a monitor to draw to.

With those two settings off, I still get a few random UI test failures. Connecting hardware monitors or screen sharing so the simulator is drawn on screen somewhere seems to resolve those though.

Answer (score 0):

I am using xcode 8.2.1 and running tests on ios 9.3 versions. One simple hack is to add a sleep for 2-5 secs after tapping on the text box and before typing on it. Though, this is not a permanent solution.

**ANOTHER RELIABLE SOLUTION**

Unselect all keyboard preferences in settings before running the tests.

```
"KeyboardAllowPaddle": false,
"KeyboardAssistant": false,
"KeyboardAutocapitalization": false,
"KeyboardAutocorrection": false,
"KeyboardCapsLock": false,
"KeyboardCheckSpelling": false,
"KeyboardPeriodShortcut": false,
"KeyboardPrediction": false,
"KeyboardShowPredictionBar": false
```